How to give .abc (Alembic file) particles random color and emmsive values?
I made a particle and volume simulation in Embergen and exported them both in their respective file formats, volume to VDB and particles to .abc.
I want to give the particles in Blender a random color and emmisive value. However blender treats alembic particles like linked objects. I mean it in the sense that the average of any value will be applied to all of them. A color ramp between blue and red makes all of them purple. Im fairly new to geometry nodes and have no Idea what I am doing.
Im going for a sparkly effect between reds, oranges, and yellows, with a little white.
I want the randomization to occur totally random. I figured out how to give the particles a random size. But I don't know what to do now.
Also I am using Blender 4.1 if that helps.
I have tried searching for similar issues online but nothing quite works for me, I even tried asking chatgpt and it was no help either.


if you don't even provide us your imported file + blend file, how shall we help you?

I did figure it out, also file is too big.
